# AJAX POST $_FILES with onclick = "return false;"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been looking to do a photo upload form using a current AJAX script.

At present I have the html form with the file input, on submit I have an onclick event with "PostForm(); return false;"

This fires off to a process.php script where the magic happens (and I have working). However, I have a success and fail message that usually pops up with the process script returning a "1" or "0" value.

I can get the form working just using "PostForm();", however the failure message appears straight away, followed by being redirected to the process page which displays "1". If I add return false; into the onclick event I get a success message however no file is uploaded.

I assume that the "return false;" command is preventing the file uploading. Is there any way to possibly show a progress bar, or a spinner whilst it uploads and then display the success / fail message?

Thanks

**Update 1**
jQuery Code

> ```
>  PostForm = function() {
>   $('.text').attr('disabled','true');
>             var data = $('form').serialize();
>             $.ajax({
>               type: 'POST',
>               url: "/lib/mp-update.php",
>               data: data,
>               cache: false,
>               success: function(html) {
>                   if(html==1) {
>                       $('#success').hide();
>                       $('#success').removeClass();
>                       $('#success').slideUp('50000');
>                       $('form').fadeOut('50000', function() {
>                            $('#success').fadeIn('50000');
>                       });
>                   } else {
>                       $('#fail').hide();
>                       $('#fail').removeClass();
>                       $('#fail').slideUp('50000');
>                       $('form').fadeOut('50000', function() {
>                            $('#fail').fadeIn('50000');
>                       });
>                   }
>               }
>             });
>             return false;
>         }
>     });
> ```

PHP does a standard switch statement to identify which form has been sent from a hidden form value.

Comment: The code would be interesting to see, because with pure ajax (XMLHttpRequest) it is not possible to post file parameters.

Comment: isn't `preventDefault()` preferred over `return false;` ?

Comment: jQuery function included in update :)

Comment: Ah.  Well, you can't post file inputs like that.

Comment: Ahh ok, could you point me in the right direction at all?

Comment: I've never used it, but there's a thing called "Uploadify" that a lot of people seem to use. It's a hybrid approach (that is, it uses Flash) because that's really the only way to do it at present.  There *might* be some HTML5-related APIs in new Firefox/Chrome updates, but I'm not familiar with those either.

Comment: I have one working (with some customization) but I used one here: http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/. It works fairly well for this, and you can modify it to take your other form input as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other people mentioned, or at least as far as I have been able to see messing with things, it's not possible to get the desired effect.

I did try Uploadify which works well if anyone else has a similar issue to what I did - http://www.uploadify.com